# DIV element didn't fit to webpage length

Tags: html, css

I have this div element that I'm using as a second background to an images added to the body element but it never does work properly as the the bottom sides never match in length.
Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fQ3k.jpg).

I did make it work once though but it always gets messed up when I modify any other elements.
I have the same problem with width too.
I hope you can help out because I'm stuck with this one.

My CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100 % ;
    width: 100 % ;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: url('../images/choc1.jpg');
    font - family: arial,
    Myriad pro,
    sans serif;
    color: #1E1B1B;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
# page {
        width: 1233.5 px;
        background - color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        position: absolute;
        margin - left: 60 px;
        margin - right: 0 px;
        margin - bottom: 0 px;
        padding: 0 px;
        min - height: 100 % ;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote up an example that should help you.

So you made the page div an absolute position element which makes it very difficult to place within other objects. Absolute is a positioning that ignores where everything else is and just gets placed. You should rarely/never use it for containers like this.

The real important line I added was `margin: 0 auto;` which puts it in the center (horizontally) of the parent container. (The container that it is inside) I also put padding on the body which pushes the page container in, rather than using margins.

You might also be able to view this codepen for a few hours: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOaEeJ

```
html
   {
     height:100%;
     width:1280px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
   }
   body
   {
     background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56d8bff4a3360ca940504574/t/5847038d3e00be622f3ce337/1481049003115/?format=1500w');
     font-family: arial,Myriad pro,sans serif;
     color:#1E1B1B;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100%;
     padding: 20px;
   }
   #page
   {
     width: 100%;
     height: 89%;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding:0px;
    }
```

Comment: thnx for the help bro but what i need is the page to not have any margin/padding from top or bottom with it seems that it never works

Comment: never mind man i followed what you did in the code an managed to get it fixed. thnx alot for  your help you're great :D :D

Answer (score 0):

for good practice give your html div a class

```
 <body>
    <div id="page" class="PageClass">
    </div>
```

in your css use the vh (view hight ) and vw (view Width)  property like so:

```
.PageClass {
  {
      **width: 100vw;**
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
      position: absolute;
     /* you wanna take this of since it is not letting you make the page ful width and giving a 60px spaing on the left */   margin-left:60px;
      margin-right:0px;
     margin-bottom:0px;
     padding:0px;
     min-height:100vh;
     }
}
```

Using vh and vw will make the div dynamic and compatible with all device sizes. effortlessly.

Good luck my friend